# What is the default Celery log level if none is specified?

Tags: python, logging, celery

According to the [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-l), the `-l/--loglevel` command line option can be used for:

> **-l, --loglevel**
>
> Logging level, choose between DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL, or FATAL.

If this option is not used and therefore no log level is specified, what is the log level used by Celery by default?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `--loglevel` flag doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Default log level in Celery is `WARNING` due implementation [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/29b62aed17e99980668984446923089f17d300c0/celery/app/log.py#L98). That level is set during [initialization](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/29b62aed17e99980668984446923089f17d300c0/celery/app/log.py#L62) of the Logging instance.

Comment: is there a way to specify this into celeryconfig.py file?