# Set Celery worker logging level

Tags: celery

In version 4.1.0 of Celery, there was a [`--loglevel` flag](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v4.1.0/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-l) which set the log level of the Celery worker.

This worked for things like `celery -A myapp worker --loglevel INFO`.

But, as of version 5.0.2, this flag has been removed from the documentation.

As of right now, if I Google "Celery worker set log level" I get links to the Celery source code, and to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44428064/2071807) which assumes its existence.

So how do you set the log level of a Celery worker now?

Comment: Seems like the flag still works, but has been removed from the documentation. Or am I losing my mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this is no longer in the documentation, `--loglevel` is still a valid parameter to `worker` in Celery 5.0.2.

```sh
celery --app my_app worker --loglevel INFO
```

Comment: did you found another stable way to do this? this way still works in furture version of celery? @LondonRob

Comment: The `--loglevel` parameter seams to be back in the documentation: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/cli.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-l